# Eclipse RCP - OLE and using "Paste Special" to paste a link

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

Is it at all possible to use OLE and "Paste Special" to paste a link from an Eclipse RCP based application into Excel?

**Some background**: I've been able to copy numeric data from my RCP based app to the clipboard, and then paste that into Excel. So far, surprisingly straight forward.

The question came however, was it possible to paste a link from my app, so that when the source numeric data changed, so did the Excel s'sheet.

I am aware of OLE as a technology that may address this requirement, but otherwise entirely out of my depth. Can someone with more understanding than I say if this is possible at all?

M.